# Lambda expressions query null field

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, nullreferenceexception

Well, I have the following query that I use to search a LIST with the text that the user has filled.

It's only one textbox that search in all these fields below, **it's working but when one of these fields is null, it's throwing a null reference exception, how can I avoid that?**

```
List<REP_MEDIDORDISPLAY> SearchFiltered = new List<REP_MEDIDORDISPLAY>();
            if (filter != String.Empty)
            {
                SearchFiltered.Clear();
                foreach (String Item in filter.Split(';').ToList<String>())
                {
                    SearchFiltered.AddRange(Medidores.Where(x => x.Data_TOI.Contains(Item.Trim()) ||
                        x.Elemento.ToUpper().Contains(Item.Trim()) ||
                        x.Fase.ToUpper().Contains(Item.Trim()) ||
                        x.ID.ToUpper().Contains(Item.Trim()) ||
                        x.KdKe.ToUpper().Contains(Item.Trim()) ||
                        x.N_Equipamento.ToUpper().Contains(Item.Trim()) ||
                        x.Status.ToUpper().Contains(Item.Trim()) ||
                        x.Tensao.ToUpper().Contains(Item.Trim())));

                }
            }
```

I hope you guys can help me. thanks.

Comment: Protip...do `string item = Item.Trim();` once at the start of the `foreach` loop, not every time! ....anyway, lot's of things can be `null` here...what is it specifically that's tripping you up?

Comment: yeap, this is true, I should use the trim before, not in all fields.

for example, the x.Elemento is null sometimes, but I do need to search on this field if it's filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By checking for `null` first:

```
(x.Elemento != null && x.Elemento.ToUpper().Contains(Item.Trim())) ||
// etc
```

Of course you should also calculate `Item.Trim()` just once and reuse this value for all tests rather than trimming as many times as there are fields.

Comment: both are right but i'm choosing you because the trim tip and you answered first.
But thank you both =)

Answer (score 2):

You can add null check to each of the properties. Example:

From

```
x.Fase.ToUpper().Contains(Item.Trim()) ||
```

To

```
 (x.Fase != null && x.Fase.ToUpper().Contains(Item.Trim())) ||
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should introduce something like a [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). This object is empty and will therefore always return false on every query against it.

If you implement nullchecks for every property on that object your code will rot over time. And you are gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you are doing, some more elegant perhaps.

One simple way could be to override the `ToString` method in the object in the `Medidores` sequence and use that for the comparison.

Something like this:

```
class Medidor {
    ... properties

    public override string ToString() {
        return Data_TOI + Elemento ... etc
    }
}
```

And then you could compare against that instead.

```
SearchFiltered.AddRange(
  Medidores.Where(x => 
    x.ToString()
     .IndexOf(Item.Trim(), 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1
);
```

I'm using `IndexOf` as it has an overload that takes `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, which ignores casing among other things.

The reason why I think this approach is preferred to what you have now, is that the `Meridor` object itself is responsible for what fields are included in the `ToString` method. Maybe it can improve readability and maintainability.